# Can Google places return the website and email address of the businesses displayed on its map?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I am a newbie to iPhone development; I was just wondering before I start off incorporating Google Places into my app whether it is possible to retrieve the email address, fax and website of a business selected on the map? 
Any help would be appreciated.